# How to avoid freezing the GUI during a loop?

Tags: c#, loops, user-interface, memory, freeze

My GUI freezes up if I run too much data, even though my process is running in another thread. in fact, that thread will keep running until it is done even while the GUI is locked up. So I think I am going something wrong in my code

```
double MeasNoAvgwrapper()
{
    double temp = 0D;
    double[] tempList = new double [MeasNoAvg];

    for(int t = 0; t < MeasNoAvg; t++)
    {
        tempList[t] = AveragePixeLink2();
    }

    temp = tempList.Average();

    return temp;
}
```

Does anyone see something wrong with it?

Comment: How do you call the method? The problem will be there since this is just the worker function. And the issue cannot be deduced from the code you are showing

Comment: If you're calling this synchronously from the UI thread, then the UI thread will have to wait for this to finish before it can do anything else (you know, like rendering UI changes).

Comment: How do you create and use the threads?

Answer (score 0):

With WinForms, you can use that to allow the `Application` to dispatch events and refresh the GUI, while disabling the form to disallow user interactions and change the mouse cursor if you need:

```
Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;  // for UX
Enabled = false;              // for UX
try
{
  for ( int t = 0; t < MeasNoAvg; t++ )
  {
    tempList[t] = AveragePixeLink2();
    Refresh();
    Application.DoEvents();   // for UI
  }
  temp = tempList.Average();
}
finally
{
  Enabled = true;
  Cursor = Cursors.Default;
}
```

You can aslo add a Cancel button disabled by default to allow to stop the process by using a conditional variable.

In this case, you can disable all controls you want the user not allowed to interact one by one by using for example a `SetFormEnabled()` method (disabling a panel disable all inner controls).

```
private bool CancelRequired;
```

```
SetFormEnabled(false);
Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
CancelRequired = false;
ButtonCancel.Enabled = true;
try
{
  for ( int t = 0; t < MeasNoAvg; t++ )
  {
    if ( CancelRequired ) break;
    tempList[t] = AveragePixeLink2();
    Refresh();
    Application.DoEvents();
  }
  temp = tempList.Average();
}
finally
{
  CancelRequired = false;
  ButtonCancel.Enabled = false;
  Cursor = Cursors.Default;
  SetFormEnabled(true);
}
```

```
private void ButtonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CancelRequired = true;
}
```

If the process takes time, you can use a progress bar on the form or in a splash box having TopMost true:

> SplashForm.cs or current form

```
public void InitProgress(int stepCount, int stepIncrement)
{
  progressBar.Minimum = 0;
  progressBar.Maximum = stepCount;
  progressBar.Value = 0;
  progressBar.Step = stepIncrement;
}

void DoProgress()
{
  progressBar.PerformStep();
  progressBar.Refresh();
}
```

> Caller form

```
SetFormEnabled(false);
var splash = new SplashForm();
splash.InitProgress(MeasNoAvg, 1);
splash.Show();
CancelRequired = false;
ButtonCancel.Enabled = true;
Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
try
{
  for ( int t = 0; t < MeasNoAvg; t++ )
  {
    if ( CancelRequired ) break;
    tempList[t] = AveragePixeLink2();
    Refresh();
    splash.DoProgress();
    Application.DoEvents();
  }
  temp = tempList.Average();
}
finally
{
  CancelRequired = false;
  ButtonCancel.Enabled = false;
  Cursor = Cursors.Default;
  splash.Close();
  SetFormEnabled(true);
}
```

Remove the use of splash if the progress bar is in the main form and set progress bar value to 0 at the end.